# numpy.concatenate of two recarrays leads to transposed shape?

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, transpose, recarray

Suppose I have two numpy arrays x1 and x2 with the same dtype but different shape:
`x1.dtype = dtype([('fmv', '<f4'), ('delta', '<f4'), ('rho', '<f4', (5,))])`

`x2.dtype = dtype([('fmv', '<f4'), ('delta', '<f4'), ('rho', '<f4', (5,))])`

`x1.shape = (10L, 1L)`

`x2.shape = (10L, 6L)`

I would like to concatenate these two arrays on axis 1:

`y = np.concatenate((x1,x2), axis=1)`

This results in:

`y.shape = (10L, 7L)` **Good**

`y['rho'].shape = (5L, 10L, 7L)` **Bad**

 Why did the field rho have it's shape transposed? I was expecting (10, 7, 5)

**UPDATE:**

```
               x1.flags | x2.flags | y.flags
C_CONTIGUOUS : True     | True     | False
F_CONTIGUOUS : False    | False    | True
OWNDATA      : False    | False    | False
WRITEABLE    : True     | True     | True
ALIGNED      : True     | True     | True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False    | False    | False
```

`x1.strides = (28L, 28L)`

`x2.strides = (168L, 28L)`

`y.strides = (28L, 280L)`

---

I made a little script you can run to duplicate the results:

`import numpy as np`

`x = np.zeros((5,3), dtype=np.dtype([('field1','<f8'),('field2','<f8',4)]))`

`A1 = np.concatenate((np.array(x[0,0], ndmin=1), np.ravel(x[:,1:], order='C')), axis=0)`

`B1 = np.concatenate((np.tile(np.array(A1[0],ndmin=2), (5,1)), np.reshape(A1[1:], (5,2), order='C')), axis=1)`

`A2 = np.ravel(x, order='C')`

`B2 = np.reshape(A2, (5,3), order='C')`

---

`B1['field2'].shape = (4L, 5L, 3L)` **Bad**

`B2['field2'].shape = (5L, 3L, 4L)` **Good**

Comment: Concatenating recarrays is not that straightforward I guess. See for example [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847710/how-do-i-add-columns-to-an-ndarray).

Comment: Can you share `x1.flags`, `x2.flags`, `y.flags`, `x1.strides`, `x2.strides` and `y.strides` with us? If both `x1` and `x2` are C-contiguous, it works as you were expecting for me.

Comment: With numpy 1.6.2 it works as expected. What version are you running?

Comment: np.version.version = '2.0.0.dev'

Comment: I see what you mean. I just ran my test script on numpy 1.6.1 and it worked as desired.

Comment: You may want to give a shout in the [numpy discussion list](http://www.scipy.org/Mailing_Lists) so they fix it.

Comment: Seems to work fine with current versions too... 2.0.0.dev sounds like a very old development version.